# Product Price at a Given Date from LeetCode

Tags: sql, union, common-table-expression

What is wrong with my code?

**QUESTION:**

**Table:**

Products: `product_id | new_price | change_date`

`(product_id, change_date)` is the primary key of this table.
Each row of this table indicates that the price of some product was changed to a new price at some date.

Write an SQL query to find the prices of all products on 2019-08-16. Assume the price of all products before any change is 10.

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT  product_id,
        new_price AS price,
        MAX(change_date) AS new_change_date
FROM Products
WHERE change_date <= CAST('2019-08-16' AS DATE)
GROUP BY product_id
),

cte2 AS (
SELECT  product_id,
        (new_price - 10) AS price,
        MIN(change_date) AS new_change_date
FROM Products
WHERE change_date > CAST('2019-08-16' AS DATE)
GROUP BY product_id
)

SELECT  DISTINCT product_id, 
        price
        FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT  DISTINCT product_id, 
        price
        FROM cte2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT product_id from cte1 
                 WHERE cte2.product_id = cte1.product_id)
```

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
{"headers": ["product_id", "price"], "values": [[**1, 20**], [2, 50], [3, 10]]}
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
{"headers": ["product_id", "price"], "values": [[**1, 35**], [2, 50], [3, 10]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`.  The first part fetches the most recent price as of the specified date.  The second gets everything else:

```
select p.product_id, p.price
from products p
where change_date = (select max(p2.change_date)
                     from products p2
                     where p2.product_id = p.product_id and
                           p2.change_date <= '2019-08-16'
                    )
union all
select p.product_id, 10
from products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from products p2
                  where p2.product_id = p.product_id and
                        p2.change_date <= '2019-08-16'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` would work in this case.

```
SELECT product_id, price
FROM
  (SELECT product_id, new_price AS price
   FROM Products
   WHERE (product_id,
          change_date) IN
       (SELECT product_id, MAX(change_date)
        FROM Products
        WHERE change_date <= '2019-08-16'
        GROUP BY product_id)
   UNION SELECT DISTINCT product_id, 10 AS price
   FROM Products
   WHERE product_id NOT IN
       (SELECT product_id FROM Products
        WHERE change_date <= '2019-08-16') ) tmp
ORDER BY price DESC
```